# Javascript replacing /, str.replace not working

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm having a really stupid issue where javascript is replacing every '/' with '%2F' in a url. Here is what i have now:

```
var url;
url = $(this).val();
url = str.replace('%2F', '/');
window.location.href = $(this).val();
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: where does the `str` variable come from?

Comment: I think you meant to put `url = url.replace('%2F', '/');`

Comment: Also, your "really stupid issue" isn't an issue. The url gets encoded, so certain characters are changed, including `/`. For example, spaces are changed to `%20`.

Comment: `location.href = encodeURI(this.value);`

Comment: thanks everyone, but I'm still getting '%2F' instead of '/'

Comment: That is because you need to use `decodeURI`, not `encodeURI`. `encodeURI` would be used to encode a string to be used in a url, so it would do the opposite of what you want to do. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the url to convert the special characters back to what they should be (like changing `%2F` back to `/`). To do this, you can use `decodeURI`:

```
url = $(this).val();
url = decodeURI(url);
```

However, sometimes spaces get replaced by `+` instead of `%20`. So, to handle these cases, you must replace all `+` with `%20` before decoding your url.

```
url = $(this).val();
url = url.replace('+', '%20');
url = decodeURI(url);
```

And now `url` is the decoded version of the url.

Comment: Still getting '%2F', is there something missing/wrong with the rest of the code when I change the last line to window.location.href = url;?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You WANT the window url to have those characters in it (like `%2F` and `%20`). Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is direct to a specific page based off of a user's selection from a form on the homepage.